# Attaching Existing Entity to New Entity (1-1 Relationship)

Tags: entity-framework-4

Consider an association in EF4 as:

Child 1----0..1 Parent

So, there's a non nullable foreign key in Parent for the Child.

I create a new Parent and assign an *existing* child. Unfortunately, this is a somewhat strange family as there are 300 parents, many sharing the same child.

When I try to save the 300 parent records, I encounter an UpdateException:

> Entities in 'MyEntities.Parents' participate in the 'Child'
>   relationship. 0 related 'Child' were found. 1 'Child' is expected.

Here's some code to illustrate:

```
// scope autosaves
using (new UnitOfWorkScope(true))
{
    var allParents= (from DataRow dataRow in this.dataTable.Rows
                     where dataRow != null
                     select CreateParent(dataRow)
                     into parents
                     where parents != null 
                     select parents).ToList();

    var parentFacade = new ParentFacade();

    foreach (var newParent in allParents)
    {
        parentFacade.Add(newParent);
    }
}

private static Parent CreateParent(DataRow dataRow)
{
    var parent = new Parent
    {
        SomeProperty = 'Moo',
        Child = GetChild(someValue)
    }

    return Parent;
}

private static Child GetChild(string someValue)
{
    return new ChildFacade().GetChild(someValue);
}

// Facade
public Child GetChild(string someValue)
{
    return (from c in this.ObjectContext.Children
            where c.SomeProperty == someValue
            select c).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I can't figure out how to get around it. I want to save a new parent with a reference to an existing child.

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> many sharing the same child.

Your relation cannot be 1 - 0..1 but one to many where one parent can have many children. Your current relation says that `Child` has optional `Parent` and `Parent` must have a `Child`.

Comment: But with a dropdown offering single choices, there can only be one choice and therefore one child? What I need then will be a 1-1? Sometimes, it's easier to put the relation in the database and then suck that back down :)

Comment: Got it. It is indeed a one-to-many from child to parent and then the foreign keys get set ok. Found your blog entry on the subject of foreign versus independant relationships and found it very enlightening. Keep up the good work! Very good.